# how to run this javascript in the <p> element 

Tags: javascript, html

this is my code :

```
<p onload=javascript:alert('sss')>www</p>
```

and the code  cant alert`'sss'`,

what's wrong with my code,

thanks

Comment: need quotes around onload and javascript: is not required.

Comment: ([An HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/) will say what is wrong for the given doc-type).

Answer (score 3):

You can try this with body element. 
Because the load event is fired when the whole document is loaded; I did not find anything about element-specific load events. So I assume that element1.onload is triggered by the same event as element2.onload - the following two bodies would be equivalent:

```
<body>
  <p onload="javascript:alert('sss')">Text</p>
  <p onload="javascript:alert('sss')">Text</p>
</body>


<body onload="javascript:alert('sss')">
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
</body>
```

**PS. that the onload event handler is now available for every HTML element in HTML5**

Comment: I have a situation where <p> tag is called only in fallback case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11028861/embed-or-object-tag-video-playback-error-handler-java-script/11032769#comment14501129_11032769 So, I am trying to trigger the java script function when <p> tag is loaded (in fall back case). According to you, in HTML5, the onload event handler is supported in all tags. But what is happening for me is, the javascript inside <p> tag is triggered when the document is loaded or the <p> tag's onload event handler is not triggering the call. Any suggestions you might have?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `onload` event can only be used with `body` or `frameset` tag. You cannot use this event with `p` tag.

For further references, go [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html).

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better served to move the javascript to the `<body>` tag:

```
<body onload="alert('sss');">
```

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, `onload` only works reliably on the `<body>` element.

Comment: According to W3C, `body` and `frameset`. According to Microsoft, pretty much anything goes. I'd agree, and go with W3C, and not attach onload to `p` elements.

Comment: Not even on `<img>` elements?

Answer (score -1):

You should have quotes around the onload and have a semicolon.

```
<p onload="javascript:alert('sss');">www</p>
```

It should also be noticed that this is not W3C standard and the onload should really be added to the body tag.

Comment: so  what event should i use ?  i want to running it Automatically

Comment: Sayem; Good call. Will update accordingly. Should have spotted that myself.