# <embed> or <object> tag video playback error handler - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, ios, cocoa-touch

Am trying to play YouTube and other videos by embedding it in the HTML source for displaying them in iOS.

Both `<embed>` and `<object>` technique works, but **none of them are capable of calling callback functions when the video fails to play or if the URL passed to it is erroneous** (and hence it could not play it).

I am using this HTML code with JavaScript for appropriate callbacks:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>video test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function errorEncountered()
{
    alert('Found error');
}
function loadingCompleted()
{
    alert("loading completed");
    //document.getElementById('youtubeObject').onerror="errorEncountered()";
    //alert(document.getElementById('youtubeObject'));
}
function clickCompleted()
{
    alert("Clicked on embedded object");
}
</script>
</head>
<body >
<div>
  <object
    id="youtubeObject"
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
    data="http://asdfasdf"
    width="643"
    height="400"
    onload="loadingCompleted()"
    onerror="errorEncountered()"
    onclick="clickCompleted()">
    <param name="movie" value="http://asdfasdf" />
    <param name="onError" value="errorEncountered()" />
    <!-- <param name="onload" value="loadingCompleted()" /> -->
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <param name="enablejsapi" value = "1" />
    <p>
    Couldn't load the video
    </p>
  </object>
</div>

<!-- document.getElementById('youtubeObject').onerror="errorEncountered()"; -->
<!-- document.getElementById('youtubeObject').addEventListener('onerror',function(){alert('error playing video')},true); -->

</body>
</html>

<!-- Actual Youtube URL "http://www.youtube.com/v/J_DV9b0x7v4" -->
```

Replacing the erroneous URL with the actual YouTube URL plays the video. But erroneous URL should trigger the JavaScript functions, that's not happening.

I have checked the [documentation of `<object>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp) and the [corresponding events](http://wap.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp). The [`<object>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp) tag docs says that the events it responds to does not has [onerror](http://wap.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onerror.asp) or [onload](http://wap.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp).
But on the other hand, the [onerror event object](http://wap.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onerror.asp) docs state that it is supported by `<img>`, `<object>`, `<script>` & `<style>` tags.

So, I tried plugging in "onerror" event with both passing it as a `<param>` to the `<object>` tag so that the plugin would handle it and alternatively, also tried it as a attribute of `<object>` tag (just trying my luck). The "onclick" attribute of object does respond but not the "onerror" and "onload".

Though my question is, why doesn't the `<param>` passed to the plugin with onerror and onload would not trigger when a erroneous URL is passed to it?

I tried with [embed tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_embed.asp), but there is no scope of attaching onerror and onload handlers using [embed](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_embed.asp) tag.

Is there a way to trigger JavaScript functions from within HTML (using embed or object technique) whenever video loading / playing fails?

PS: I have stumbled upon some links discussing this issue, but none of them end up with a solution, that's why I started this new question, and I am doing this for a iOS-specific case.

[Detect <embed> tag failing to load video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490529/detect-embed-tag-failing-to-load-video)

http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=590

Thanks for any suggestions & help.

**Additions:**
The alternative content loading in the tags between `<object>` & `</object>` will display the content in iPad simulator, but not on the device itself. Even this is one of the puzzles I am finding hard to crack.

PS: I had already tried the  method, for youtube specific I have tried adding the onError callback, but it never triggers! Have used the normal youtube specified way where we can plug in onError callback for youtube: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player

Problem with the above is, we have to create a `YT.Player`and set the videoID to the object. This would make it impossible to play videos from other sources. So used a slightly unconventional way:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>video test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function errorEncountered(event)
{
    alert('Found error');
}
function errorFound()
{
    alert('Found error');
}
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.sandeshkadur.com/wp-content/themes/Gaia/js/video.js?ver=1.0'></script>

</head>
<body id="mainBody">
<iframe id = "youtube_vid" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/28723846?color=ffffff" frameborder="0" width="640" height="360"></iframe>

<!-- From https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/youtube-api-gdata/myLe-SdMZ6w/tziw7W2LBv4J -->
<!-- <iframe  id="youtube_vid" src="asdfasdf"></iframe> -->
<script>
var player = document.getElementById("youtube_vid");
new YT.Player(player, {
            events: {
                'onStateChange': function(){console.log(arguments)},
                'onError': errorEncountered
            }
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This though it plays the video properly, it dows not get error callbacks for Youtube links atleast!

Comment: Well I can tell you exactly why '[it will] display the content in iPad simulator, but not on the device itself'. The simulator is just that, a simulator. Apple cheats and basically takes your iOS calls and converts them to Mac OS calls, which can handle Flash and other things. Worse, there's no mechanisms to warn you when you do something on the simulator that an iOS device can't. While its obvious `simulator != real device`, it is so in many ways. You can get the simulator to do a lot of things a real device can't or won't do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the new `<iframe>` embed code:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

YouTube will detect what platform the user is using and serve the appropriate code, i.e. Flash for desktop users, `<video>` for iOS, etc.

You can find this embed code (in any YouTube video page) by clicking on the Share button, then the Embed button.

---

**Update:** You are **not** going to find a general solution that will play any video from any provider on iOS devices. The provider has to specifically encode the video so that is can be played by the `<video>` element in Safari.

I suggest:

- Find the embed code for every video site you support (not the FLV source URL, the embed code that the site gives to users).
- If the site uses `<iframe>` then they probably support playback on iOS. Use this code verbatim.
- If the site uses a Flash player, use [SWFObject](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to embed the video instead of their `<embed>` code. If SWFObject detects that the browser does not support Flash, it can show some alternate content instead (e.g. a message like "Sorry, you need to have Flash to view this video").
- Use a giant `switch` statement:

  ```
  switch (videoType):
  case 'YouTube':
      // use YouTube iframe code
      break;

  case 'Vimeo':
      // use Vimeo iframe code
      break;

  // ...on and on...

  default:
      // use SWFObject to embed
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, please check the details I have added to question. I had already tried the <iframe> method, and reasons of why it is not suitable I have explained in my new edit.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `type="application/x-shockwave-flash"` in the `object tag` but where are you defining the fallback for `iOS`. If you trying to do target `iOS` specifically then why not use `video` tag. The documentation given in http://websitehelpers.com/video/html.html will help you to play video in `iOS` For `iOS` you need to define the `video tag` otherwise it does not understand or you can use any one flash player like `flowplayer` which has a fallback support for `iOS`. You can refer the documentation from http://flash.flowplayer.org/plugins/javascript/ipad.html. Try and let me know if this solves your issue

**Update :**

Try the following `<iframe id="frame" title="Youtube Video" width="320" height="194" scrolling="no" src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/J_DV9b0x7v4' frameborder="1"></iframe>` . This works well in `desktop` and in `ipad`. `J_DV9b0x7v4` is the video you want to play. Check the demo from http://jsfiddle.net/AAUgG/ in `iOS`. This should solve the purpose as you desired.

Comment: Will surely try what you have suggested, before that I forgot to mention important thing in the question. If I use <video> tag, the problem with that is I cannot use a YouTube URL, for instance,  to play the youTube video. Coz the streaming URL of youtube is wrapped inside of the URL which points to that particular page. And the streaming URL of youtube is hidden and not accessible but to Youtube page itself.

Comment: <video> tag simply cannot play the direct Youtube URL, so I guess we cannot use <video> tag and hence the HTML 5 approach. Please correct me if I am wrong anywhere.

Comment: Yes you cannot use <video> tag for this since there is a redirect link and also the HTML5 approach

Comment: You can use iframe or quicktime player to play in desktop but it will not work in ipad. So for ipad you need to pass the url so that it opens with the youtube player. I tried the url in your question in the address bar of safari in ipad and it opened the youtube link url in the app and played there whereas in desktop it does not. So you cannot use any player instead you need to pass the url to the app to play

Comment: @Raj : Check the update in my answer. This works in ipad.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I cannot use <video> tag for the reasons that it redirects internally. Next, I have already tried the youtube's iFrame method. It does play the video, but it fails in intimating of wrong URL's or of videos which cannot be played. That is what I am exactly trying to find out, how to trigger a javascript in cases when the video is unable to load.

Comment: Can you give any such url so that i can check it

Comment: I am just trying first to get callback for wrong URL's, say remove a character from the same youtube URL above: http://www.youtube.com/v/J_DV9b0x Next, I yet do not know how to get callbacks for the video URLs which cannot be played by the native player.

Comment: You need to [subscribe to the `onError` event](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events) (YouTube iframe API) and check the return value.

Comment: @steveax - Yes, I have tried that on iframe tag. Not getting the the onError event handler though I subscribe for it, besides it is just YouTube specific. What am I supposed to do videos from different hosters? I had already tried <iframe> method but had not included in my question, please check the recent addition to the question.

Comment: @Raj as @jeffery-to notes, you'll have to handle error events for each source separately - there is no universal solution to handle videos from YouTube, Vimeo, etc. Aside from that though, it doesn't appear that you are even loading the YouTube iframe API JavaScript and as the google groups thread in your comments notes, the error event is only fired after the `playVideo` event is attempted. I couldn't get the YouTube js to play nicely in a fiddle, but [here's a demo](http://sandbox.pangram.net/vid.html)

Comment: @steveax - Thanks for your reply, I understand that I will have to check for whitelist of all video hosters as suggested by Jeffery and embed through their own way of iframe mechanism. Now what is the fallback for say some videos which are not in part of my whitelist? Havent anybody dealt with it earlier?